Why does a group of charges with spherical symmetry, where each oscillates radially while retaining spherical symmetry, not radiate?
I am thinking about the problem, "Why does a group of charges with spherical symmetry, where each oscillates radially while retaining spherical symmetry, not radiate?" I figured out that with a spherically symmetric charge distribution, there only exists a monopole scalar potential which is time-independent. However, I do not have any clue about what spherical symmetry implies for the magnetic vector potential. Can anyone give me some ideas about this?

this is far from an answer, but consider the following: each moving charge does radiate in a direction perpendicular to the radial axis, i.e. tangentially to the surface of the sphere. So there must be interference between the different radiating charges, which my intuition tells me should cancel in the limit of a continuous spherical charge distribution.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139819/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38517/2451 and links therein.

Radiation would have to be spherically symmetric. Both the E and B vectors would have to be radial. Suppose either had a tangential component at some point. If you rotate the system around the axis through that point and the center, everything should look the same. You should also see a component in the rotated direction. You can't have two non-zero tangential vectors at the same point. The tangential component has to be zero.
But that means E and B are parallel. That isn't possible for radiation.
